# filesytem read/write in google app engine laravel 4

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-4

I am trying to set the path of my laravel application  at Google Storage Path. I am reading [this tutorial](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/) at section6 it describes what to do. I followed that steps and at 
bootstrap/paths.php I have this

```
const BUCKET_NAME = 'fleetmanagement';
$storage_path = "gs://" . BUCKET_NAME . "/storage";
mkdir($storage_path);
return array(

    'app' => __DIR__ . '/../app',

    'public' => __DIR__ . '/../public',

    'base' => __DIR__ . '/..',

    'storage' => $storage_path,
);
```

But during configuration (cmd commad for composer update) it shows this warninig:

> Warning: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "gs" - did you
>   forget to enab le it when you configured PHP? in
>   C:\national-fleet\vendor\ajessup\gae-laravel\s
>   rc\Ajessup\GaeLaravel\GaeApplication.php on line 24
>
> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"file_put_contents(/meta/services.
>   json): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory","file":"C:\national-fl
>   eet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php","l
>   ine":71}}
>
> Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in
>   C:\national-fleet\bootstrap\paths .php on line 5

Answer (score 1):

Not related to GAE, but I got this error, because some folders in /app/storage were missing

To fix the error, I manually created the following folders:

```
app/storage/
app/storage/cache/
app/storage/logs/
app/storage/meta/
app/storage/sessions/
app/storage/views/
```

then I deleted the contents of my vendor folder and ran composer update again